# Can't Get jQuery to work locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, load

Hey there I have checked over more jQuery questions like this than I care to recall but I really cannot seem to figure this out.

The following code just WILL NOT work locally. Haven't had a chance to test it online yet, but surely I should be able to test locally.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang='en' xml:lang='en' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery test</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/root/WebDev/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.css'/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/root/WebDev/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/root/WebDev/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div style="height: 20px;width:20px;background-color:red;position:relative;top:50px;left:50px;"></div>
</body>
```

And the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div').click(function(){
    $('div').effect('explode');
});

});
```

just as a note, I do have those jquery files locally.

Comment: Any errors in your JavaScript console? Also, why do you appear to include the jQuery file 3 times?

Comment: your jquery should come first in the list of js files.... what is jquery.js and jquery-1.9.1.min.js loaded that too from different paths...

Comment: you loaded 2 jquery-1.9.1 in incorrect sequence?

Comment: "*And the jQuery code:*" ...where did you put it? What is the right path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First put jQuery, than the other plugins, scripts, libraries **that make use of jQuery!**

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/root/WebDev/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/root/WebDev/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

For the last one, if that's the file where you have your functions, make sure the path is also the right one,

- I'm not quite sure for this path you used:

  `/root/WebDev/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom/js/jquery-1.9.1.js`
- Are `jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom/js/` really the names of your folders? :)
- And why you don't use `Google Hosted Libraries` and some nice `HTML5` markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link  href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="myfunctions.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>All you need</title>
</head>
<body>

   <div style="height: 20px;width:20px;background-color:red;position:relative;top:50px;left:50px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it didn't work :(
I even tried changing my jquery so that i'm just using normal jquery and not ui. still not working though :(. and yeah those are the correct folders, bad file management i know lol

Comment: @DanielBowen you should try harder. There's no other reasonable explanation :\

Comment: @DanielBowen Please use my complete code snippet, just make sure to set the correct path to `myfunctions.js` where you'll paste inside the "click effect" code you need.

Comment: You sir are some sort of witch doctor! haha nah, I dont know why my local files wouldn't work but I do now understand that i got the order wrong, I wasn't aware that they had an order (but now I do).

Comment: @DanielBowen :) ohh finally this mistery is resolved! :D happy coding! have fun! (and have some sleep too ;) )

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27451/discussion-between-daniel-bowen-and-roxon)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the leading slashes from your href and src attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the web itself cant find the jquery file. Try to use page.resolveurl

Page.ResolveUrl to always return its URLs as an app-absolute path.

Resolve URL always gives you the root of virtual directory.

e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%=page.resolveurl("~/javascript/jquery-ui.js")%>'></script>
```